# Use Vertex Painter for texturing?

Tags: vertex-paint, blend-modes

I'm trying to use Vertex paint to texturing my cube. But colors never show-up in the UVmap window or when export it !? 
[image: vertex1]
I don't know where is my fault.

Comment: Don't you want Texture Paint instead Vertex Paint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *[Vertex Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/vertex_paint/introduction.html)* you are directly coloring model's mesh - so this technique doesn't use UV mapping to apply any kind of texture.

If you want to paint a texture (image), you need to switch to *[Texture Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/texture_paint/introduction.html)* mode insted of *Vertex Paint*.